# How to understand the double probability integral satisfying Fubini theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

When I study the Parsevel Relation in probability theory, I meet a problem. In the proof of uniqueness of characteristic function, there is following content.

"Since $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ have the same characteristic function, Parsevel Relation implies that

$$\int e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}Q_1(dx)=\int e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}Q_2(dx)$$
for $-\infty<v<\infty$ and $\sigma>0$. Multiply both sides by $\sigma/\sqrt{2\pi}$, integrate over the integral $(-\infty,a)$ with respect to Lebesgue mesure, and apply the Fubini Theorem to obtain
$$\int\int_{(-\infty,a)}\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dvQ_1(dx)=\int\int_{(-\infty,a)}\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dvQ_2(dx)$$
for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma>0$.

Forgiving my lack of knowledge in real analysis, I can not quite understand the "**Fubini Theorem**" part. I checked the Fubini theorem on Wikipedia. The precondition of using Fubini theorem is verifying $\int\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}d(\mu(x)\times\nu(v))$ is finite, or $\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is measurable in $X\times Y$, where $X$
is probability space for $Q_1$ or $Q_2$, $Y$ is $(-\infty,a)$, and $\mu,\nu$ is corresponding measure of $X$ and $Y$. How to prove? I am very confusing...

P.S. I made my own proof but not very self-confident to convince that is right. Since $\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is density function of the normal distribution $N(x,\sigma^{-1})$, we have

$$\int_{X\times Y}\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}d(\mu(x)\times\nu(v))=\int_{X\times Y} F(x<\hat{X}<x+dx,v<\hat{Y}<v+dv),$$
where $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ is corresponding random variable satisfying the distribution of $Q_i$ and $N(x,\sigma^{-1})$.

It turns the product integral to calculating probability of two events. Trivially the right side of equation above is finite since it is a probability space. Hence  the finiteness of  $\int\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}d(\mu(x)\times\nu(v))$ is proved.

I don't know whether my proof is precise. Please help if you are the expert on it. Thanks very much.

Comment: For non-negative measurable functions there is no integrability condition.

Comment: So how to prove measurable? I know the question is too basic but that is what I want to know... @geetha290krm

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable.

Comment: I have considered it. But I think it is not quite suitable here. $\frac{\sigma e^{-\sigma^2(x-v)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is definitely measurable in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, but here we consider the product space of $dv\times Q(dx)$, not $dv\times dx$, I think...

Comment: X is a probability space, $Q$ is the measure, or so called distribution.

Comment: I am sorry I do not quite follow you. $x-v$ is just subtraction  of two real numbers.

Comment: $Q$ is supposed to be defined on the Borel $\sigma $ algebra of $\mathbb R$. So Borel measurability of the function is enough for $dv \times dQ$ measurability.